# PDO email verification

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo

I am trying to make a user registration script.

In my `registration.php` script, I validate user inputs then insert them into database. I then want to send the user a verification link in an email using SMTP with:

```
$user_activation_hash = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)); //creating ramdom string

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Host       = "info";         // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "info"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "info";                 // SMTP account password
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                       // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = info;                       // set the SMTP port for the server

    $mail->From       = "info"; //the email the mail comes from
    $mail->FromName   = "someName";                 //what name should be shown at the email
    $mail->AddAddress($email);                      //where the mail should be sent to
    $mail->Subject    = "email validation";         //subject of the mail

    //how the link should look in the mail the "url" should point to the verification.php file
    $link = "url path to my verification.php script".'?verification_code='.urlencode($user_activation_hash);

    //the message in the mail with the above link
    $mail->Body = "Please click on this link to activate your account:".' '.$link;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "there was an error sending the mail" . ' ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

        //if there is an error sending the mail then I delete it here

        return false;

    } else {
        //here I update the user with the new random created string

        $sql = 'UPDATE `user` SET verification = :verification WHERE Id = :Id';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':verification', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $dbh = null;

        return true;
    }
```

All of this works fine so far the registered user gets an email with the random link created.

here is an example of the link the user gets: http://url/to/verification.php?verification_code=80371b8ff9b0d5fb444f4be68c8b5a0d9757603b

When they click the link they are directed to my verification.php script:

```
if(!empty($_GET['verification_code']) && isset($_GET['verification_code'])){
$verificationCode = $_GET['verification_code'];

//check the database for the verification code from the link
$sql = 'SELECT Id, verification FROM `user` WHERE verification = :verification AND isActive = 0';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':verification', $verificationCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$Id = $row['Id'];

if (empty($row)){
        echo "the account was not found";
    }else{
        //if they match. make the user active in db
        $sql = 'UPDATE user SET isActive = 1, verification = NULL WHERE Id=:Id';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        echo "The account has been activated!";
    }

}
}
```

Okay so here is my headache and I hope I can explain it properly:

All of this works. When I create the first user it works after registration I can see a verification code in the database and when I click the link it gets activated. But the following users getting registered is being activated at once when I hit the registration.php script! It is like both scripts are being run at once and then making the activation link completely unnecessary.

I have no idea what causes this behavior. Is it because my pdo connection isn't closed properly from my first script? Is it because PHP normally just runs all scripts in a directory when only one I called? Is it because I don't understand how the $_GET function works?

I can't possible find a way why this shouldn't work so here is some of the things I have already tried:

- I have tried registering a user with the verification.php script commented out then first uncomment it and click the link being send when the user is registered. this works.
- I have tried moving my verification.php script to another folder. Didn't help anything
- I have tried closing the connection in the verification.php then made a new PDO after. this didn't work either.
- I have tried alot of ways to change the $_GET method but no success.

UPDATE!: now i have tried to see exactly where the code breaks and i noticed something unusual. when the registration.php is run the user is set in the database as not active. As soon as i recieve the email with the link. the user is set to active, without ever clicking the link

Please tell me someone out there knows what's up.

Comment: after the first user has been activated. It's verification value is null. The next user who arrives at the verification page, whos verification_code is not set (meaning null). Performs the following query: select from users where verification = null. And this returns the first user.

Comment: yes but before the second user, uses the verification.php he has registered an account hence getting a new verification code which he uses from the email?

Comment: You haven’t shown us where `$Id` is supposed to come from in the first script.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't include it because i know that part works fine the user always gets registered. it comes from a $_POST function from a html form

Comment: oh i'm sorry that's not correct that is all user information. the Id originates in my mysql database and i use sql SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=:email because the email is always unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the first user when registered the table was completely empty
but when the second user registered and enter the verification.php with no get value it searches for the user that has verification = null (the first user)
and complete the code esily so all you need is to modify your code

just edit the first query in the verification.php file instead of this

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, verification FROM `user` WHERE verification = :verification';
```

do it like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, verification FROM `user` WHERE verification = :verification AND isActive = 0';
```

for the checking that if the value is sent or not

```
if(isset($_GET["verification_code"]){
    $sql = 'SELECT Id, verification FROM `user` WHERE verification = :verification AND isActive = 0';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':verification', $verificationCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    $Id = $row['Id'];

    if ($Id == null){
        echo "the account was not found";

    }else{

// check if the verificationcode found in the database, matches the verificationcode from the link
if ($row['verification'] !== $verificationCode) {

    //checking if it already exists and if there is an error then deleting the user

} else {

    //if they match. make the user active in db
    $sql = 'UPDATE user SET isActive = 1, verification = NULL WHERE Id=:Id';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    echo "The account has been activated!";

}
}
}
```

Comment: this didn't work. But verification.php gets its GET value from the link? Am i correct? i will just update the question with an example of my link sent to the registered user

Comment: the first thing the only way to do this is the Get value from the URL this is not the problem your problem were solved is you change the isActive value to the default value that enter it in the database and the other thing you might do is to check if the get value is sent or not i am editing my answer for this

Comment: This seems to be working! I can't quite figure out why though.. because now my $verificationCode is empty? how can it possibly still find the user and run the UPDATE? when $verificationCode is empty i can't find the user with the select method? can i?

Comment: the select and update statement doesn't run until the verification_code param sent in the url by Get method unless this you may add some else to echo message if the user is tried to enter the page without sent verification_code and you may check for  the row count after the select statment

Comment: the fully activated user has verification is null and the get equal null so the code run easily before adding the if statement

Comment: Okay i get that it first runs in the if isset statement. But that doesnt explain how it can still work now that my variable called $verificationCode is empty?

Comment: I can't understand you what is the problem now does the code work or not

Comment: well no.. it works correct in the database with your changes. but on the frontend it always just echos "the account was not found"

Comment: i have updated the question you can now see my verification.php uses the isset function but it still does the same as before

Comment: As your code the massage the user not found is from the if (empty ($row)) the better way to do this using rowcount () http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php